# extjs triggerfield doesn't fire blur

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, blur

**Update**: I tried a suggestion by @newmount however, if I call `fireEvent('blur')` then the focus of the trigger isn't fired by any keyboard action. (It resumes once there is a mouse click)

---

To be honest the [triggerfield](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Trigger) doesn't fire [blur](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Trigger-event-blur) in a certain situation.

From within the focus event if I have a reference to another field and do `field.focus()` the blur of the current field doesn't fire. What's worse is it fires later if I click anywhere else.

Below is code and steps to reproduce:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

  Ext.define('Ext.ux.CustomTrigger', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Trigger',
    alias: 'widget.customtrigger',
    labelStyle: 'white-space: nowrap',
    initComponent : function() {
        this.on("focus", function() {
            console.log("Trigger focused");
            //the problem point.
            //I do some processing here and then 
            //in some case I do the following:
            Ext.getCmp('some_field').focus();
            //when this is called the BLUR of this trigger field isn't fired.
        });
        this.on("blur", function() {
            console.log("Trigger blurred");
        });
        this.callParent();
    }
  });
//end of onReady 
});
```

Here is a live fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sq37s/

To Reproduce:

- Click into the first name field
- Hit tab, it will jump into the trigger and then jump into the *mid init* field.
- The console at this point will **not** show a *Trigger blurred*
- Now click anywhere in the panel and you'll see *Trigger blurred*.

This behavior is causing some very unexpected issues in our application, this is something so trivial we based assumptions on the fact that something like this will work.

I would love:

- Any suggestions to work around this, perhaps pure javascript
- Any hope of getting the [extjs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271353/michael-mullany) [guys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925782/mitchell-simoens) to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the focus gets changed programmatically, the event may not get fired (think events gets fired only on user-action). One workaround is to fire that event programmatically while changing focus

```
this.on("focus", function(e) {
    console.log("Trigger focused");
    if (someConditionToChangeFocus){
        e.fireEvent('blur'); //Fires the blur event
        Ext.getCmp('some_field').focus();
    }
});
```

[Edit]

Another approach is to use FocusManager's [beforecomponentfocus](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.FocusManager-event-beforecomponentfocus) event, fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3mq

Comment: I tried this out, a funny thing that is happening now is after doing a `fireEvent('blur')` tabing (or Shift tabbing) back into the trigger doesn't fire the focus!

Comment: Hi, thanks very much. I looked at your example, however a similar sort of issue persists. When I tab from the first field, the caret jumps from the trigger into `some_field`, however, the _customtrigger lost focus_ isn't printed on the console. If it were any other field, say a textfield, the focus **and** the blur events of the field would fire.